# Edit my script to get ips based on Iam label

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

Is there a gcloud command to get all the gcp project labels and `--filter` by organization. Please have a look at the screenshot:

[![gcp_org_screenshot][1]][1]

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), so that it becomes better readable.

Comment: Please include sample input, current output and expected output.

Comment: What do you mean by organization label? You need to run this script on several organization at a time? And what is the IAM part? It's not clear

Comment: These are the fields Ihave in my output file now.
name zone machine_type preemptible internal_ip external_ip status service_account project_id.

I want to include All Projects --> in IAM&Admins--> under LABELS--> organization(key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single command that lists labels.
You can list projects in selected organization, then list labels in each of these projects:

```
#!/bin/bash
for PROJECT in $(gcloud projects list --filter="parent.id=ORGANIZATION_ID" --format="value(name)");
do
gcloud projects describe $PROJECT --format="value(labels)";
done
```

You can find more information on listing and filtering [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/it-ops/filtering-and-formatting-fun-with).